# Create TRIGGER to insert after the insertion of specific value

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have the following

**TABLE #1** `id` `time` `sender` `receiver` `message` `status` `aux_id`

**TABLE #2** `time_to_send` `sender` `receiver` `message` `aux_id`

The `TABLE #2` has a process that sends the data to an api which returns a Boolean.

So if the process success

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE #1` (time,sender,receiver,message,status,aux_id) 
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'sender','receiver','message','OK','1')
```

If doesn't

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE #1` (time,sender,receiver,message,status,aux_id) 
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'sender','receiver','message','ERROR','1')
```

I want to create a TRIGGER to **REINSERT** the data to `TABLE #2` **IF** the process insert into the `status` field `ERROR` value.

I'm trying this without success

```
mysql> DELIMITER ||
mysql> USE db 
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER resend
-> ON TABLE #1
-> AFTER INSERT
-> AS
-> IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE #1 WHERE status LIKE 'ERROR' AND aux_id =! 2)
-> BEGIN
-> INSERTO INTO TABLE #2 (time_to_send,sender,receiver,message,aux_id)
-> VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MIN),NEW.sender,NEW.receiver,NEW.message,'2')
-> END;||
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the trigger syntax wrong. Try something like (I don't fully understand the scenario so you will have to adjust the logic in the trigger):

```
delimiter @
create trigger resend 
after insert on t1 
for each row 
    IF NEW.status = 'ERROR' THEN     
        INSERT INTO t2 (time,sender,receiver,status,aux_id)     
        VALUES (NEW.time,NEW.sender,NEW.receiver, NEW.status, NEW.aux_id); 
    END IF @

delimiter ;
```